# CURDATE() return wrong result

Tags: 7, datetime, database

I have write sql query in drupal looks like this.

Let's assume **today's date is 2013-07-24 and total of node is 4**.

```
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) amount FROM {node} n 
              LEFT JOIN {flagging} f ON n.nid = f.entity_id AND f.fid = '1'
              LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_tarikh_tamat_passport} ttp ON n.nid = ttp.entity_id AND (ttp.entity_type = 'node' AND ttp.deleted = '0')
              WHERE (( (n.status = '1') AND (n.type IN  ('data_pekerja')) AND (ttp.field_tarikh_tamat_passport_value > CURDATE()) AND (f.uid IS NULL ) ))";
$result = db_query($query)->fetch();
print $result->amount;
```

The output of code **above is 3** but with this code **below is 1**

```
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) amount FROM {node} n 
                  LEFT JOIN {flagging} f ON n.nid = f.entity_id AND f.fid = '1'
                  LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_tarikh_tamat_passport} ttp ON n.nid = ttp.entity_id AND (ttp.entity_type = 'node' AND ttp.deleted = '0')
                  WHERE (( (n.status = '1') AND (n.type IN  ('data_pekerja')) AND (ttp.field_tarikh_tamat_passport_value > '2013-07-24') AND (f.uid IS NULL ) ))";
    $result = db_query($query)->fetch();
    print $result->amount;
```

The different of this sql query is only the value of **CURDATE() and '2013-07-24'**

Can you please explain why the output is different? I need the query to displaying total of node that has date field value greater than today.

Comment: Can we see a dump of those rows?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal usually stores dates as Unix timestamps, not regular date strings. Have a look at your field_data_field_tarikh_tamat_passport table to confirm which data format you're working with. If it's a timestamp, update your query to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() instead of CURDATE().

Comment: the format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: I'm using date module for this field.